# Form control options not showing in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, form-control

Take look at the code : https://github.com/Jony-Jas/check

The options of form-control is not showing in mobile and in Ubuntu but working with windows.

Website: https://jony-jas.github.io/check/

Help me finding the bug.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the ui. The `window.speechSynthesis` is an experimental API. Many browsers and platforms don't support it. So, from the `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()` function returns undefined and the options don't get populated. Before running other codes, you can check if the device or browser support `window.speechSynthesis`.